# Why are COM DLLs referred to as 'servers'?

Tags: dll, com, terminology

Why are COM DLLs referred to as 'servers'?

I realise that COM clients will be utilising the COM DLL by creating objects and calling functions etc.

But a 'server' is meant to be an actual process running in the OS.  Why then is the term 'server' applied to COM DLLs?

Comment: You already answered your own question: because the DLL is consumed by "client" applications, to which it provides services. Calling it a "server" is therefore the most apt mental model.

Comment: @CodyGray: so in Java would you call a `.jar` file a 'server' in the same way?

Comment: I don't know anything about Java. Are `.jar` files code files or executable files?

Comment: @CodyGray: `.jar` files are like compiled libraries of classes. Java programs can create objects defined in `.jar` files, much like objects can be created from a COM DLL, but no one calls `.jar` or `.class` files 'servers'.

Comment: Having no idea how the COM server is actually implemented is a pretty big deal in COM.  You can state your preference with the CLSCTX argument of CoCreateInstance() but what you'll actually get is determined by config.  Routinely taken advantage of in COM+ and with COM surrogates for example.  You can get a EXE to host the server.  Or a remote machine.  A server.

Comment: @HansPassant: so you're accepting that the DLL itself is not the 'server'?

Answer (score 6):

That is how [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) model and terminology is defined. There are clients and servers. *This terminology is not affected by how a particular COM server is hosted*, or how a particular COM client connects to said server -- *that* would just be confusing! :)

(The DLL itself is not a COM server: rather, a COM DLL *contains* a COM server.)

In an ideal world there is *no reason* to need to distinguish between an out-of-process COM object (which *is* hosted like the "classical" definition of a server in a separate process) and an in-process COM object. However, just because it is in-process doesn't mean that it's direct access, and COM will marshal across thread boundaries! (In this case, a physical manifestation of a "classical server" *still* applies, just at a sub-process level.)

I think [this is a good brief intro](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/comintro.aspx). I think it is better to compare [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) to [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture) than just libraries or classes. That is, COM defines the *rules of communication* as well. This is not present in most libraries -- e.g. classes in JAR files or non-COM DLLs -- which effectively just contain "code to execute".

Happy coding.

---

Here is a [definition of COM](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/16368/component-object-model-com) that I think is relevant:

> Component Object Model+ (COM+) is a binary interoperability standard defined by Microsoft that specifies a model for distributed object communication. **COM+ defines communication by separating objects into clients and servers.** The client is defined as an object that wants to access a particular service, while **the server is an object that provides service.** The client and server can communicate with each other independently of the programming language in which they are defined and independently of the operating system that lies between them.

Comment: I still think you need a process for it be a server. A class library with a fancy set of rules doesn't make it a server.

Comment: @GaryJones See the first paragraph. Also, it is entirely valid for multiple "servers" to exist within the same process, which is effectively what cross-thread marshaling has to do. It is *the* terminology used and it makes perfect sense considering the *grand scope* of COM. An in-process DLL is just *one* manifestation, as is an out-of-process EXE,  and yet *both* still follow the same "fancy set of rules" :)

Comment: @GaryJones Also server in COM sense refers to logical interaction/model, not the physical manifestation -- although, as noted above (and in defense of why such term is quite valid), both in-process and out-of-process have a physical "server" manifestation. The DLL itself is *not* the COM server.

Answer (score 2):

The term "server" is used in a fairly loose sense, in that it is *a component that provides services*. The fact that a particular component might be available as an in-process DLL is an implementation detail.

Comment: It seems that the word 'server' is inappropriate for a file that simply acts as a code library to create objects etc.

Answer (score 1):

A DLL provides services to clients. So analogous to Client-Server model in networks we call DLLs as servers as well.